# Creating AmazonDynamoDBClient with AWSCredentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, android-studio, amazon-dynamodb

We are developing a basic game for android phones and have recently switched from Eclipse IDE to Android Studios. With the switch, I was forced to move from **aws-java-sdk-1.9.30** to **aws-android-sdk-2.2.0**.

I have attempted to update the AWS code and it is now compiling, however I have come across an issue while creating the `AmazonDynamoDBClient`.

I am getting this runtime error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no HostnameVerifier specified
```

I'm not sure if I am missing a step somewhere. If anyone can help shed some light on what may be causing the issue, I will be very thankful!

On a related note, most of the examples I have been able to find, and the examples on which I based my initial code, seem to be for the **aws-java-sdk-1.9.30** jars. If anyone knows of where I can find examples that are suited for the **aws-android-sdk-2.2.0** jars, it would help immensely!

Here is the entire stack trace as requested:

```java
CLIENT:com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient@5ef04b5
Creating Match Details...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no     HostnameVerifier specified
at     javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setHostnameVerifier(HttpsURLConnection.java:265)
at     com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.configureConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:169)
at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.createConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:105)
at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:60)
at     com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:361)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:211)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2930)
at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.query(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1240)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:2181)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper.query(DynamoDBMapper.java:2137)
at com.towerfield.aws.MatchDetails.getMatchIds(MatchDetails.java:201)
at com.towerfield.aws.MatchDetails.<init>(MatchDetails.java:109)
at com.towerfield.aws.MatchDetails.main(MatchDetails.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here is where the exception is thrown (inside HTTPSURLConnection.java):

```java
public void setHostnameVerifier(HostnameVerifier v) 
{
    if (v == null) 
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("HostnameVerifier is null");
    }
    hostnameVerifier = v;
}
```

Here is the relevant code which seems to be causing the runtime error:

```java
static AmazonDynamoDBClient client;
...
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("KEY","SECRETKEY");
client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
...
DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
...
List<PlayersListOfActiveMatches> latestReplies = mapper.query(PlayersListOfActiveMatches.class, queryExpression);
```

---

Here is a list of my imports as was requested:

```java
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import   com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBAttribute;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBHashKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBMapper;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBQueryExpression;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBRangeKey;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.dynamodbv2.dynamodbmapper.DynamoDBTable;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Condition;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
```

Comment: 1st note: if you are going to be using static credentials, you might as well use the provided `BasicAWSCredentials`  class. 2nd: please provide full stack trace. 3rd: can you provide your package imports and possibly an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Thanks a bunch @MikeKobit. I have completed your suggestions for 1, 2, and half of 3. I will work on a MCVE as soon as possible. in the mean time please let me know if the changes I have made have helped you assess my issue. My friends and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

DynamoDB examples for the AWS SDK for Android are available in the AWS [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/dynamodb_om.html).